# The code of method XYZ is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Tags: android, memory-management, methods

I have created an android application, in that I use more than 25,000 lines in one method, so, it gives error - **The code of method XYZ is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit**

How to resolve this ?

Comment: You have split it in parts... that is only way to resove this problem in android or java

Comment: @RamaniAshish How ?????

Comment: @SwetaSharma you have to optimize your code.

Comment: @pratik I had optimize my code at maximum level.

Comment: @SwetaSharma optimize means do optimization and split your methods as well, I mean to say that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55844/discussion-between-sweta-sharma-and-pratik).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose your code is

```
your function()
{ 
   if(a == 0)
    {
        //lines of code
    }
    else
    {
        //lines of code
    }
}
```

above function exceeds limit then you can do it like this

```
your function()
{ 
   if(a == 0)
    {
        //call a0 function
    }
    else
    {
        //call a!0 function
    }
}

your a0()
{ 

    //lines of code for a == 0

}

your a!0()
{ 

    //lines of code for a != 0

}
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: if it reaaly helpful to you then plz accept it as answer...!

Comment: can we go for chat../

Comment: Please dont discuss personal chat here.! Use chat room for that

Comment: @SwetaSharma have you did this completely?

Comment: @SwetaSharma you can split your method and you can optimize your code as well.

Comment: @SwetaSharma need any help?

Comment: How to restore inapp billing ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to split your method into several ones.

For example convert this:

```
private void xyz() {
    task1;
    task2;
    ...
    taskN;
}
```

into this:

```
private void xyz() {
    doTask1();
    doTask2();
    ...
    doTaskN();
}

private void doTask1() {
    task1;
}
private void doTask2() {
    task2;
}
...
private void doTaskN() {
    taskN;
}
```

You have to think about the logic of your code and try to identify the different tasks is doing. Then gather all the lines related to a task into one method and simply call this method from your `xyz()` method.

Moreover, it will make the code more readable and easy to maintain. Generally you should avoid creating such a long method.

Comment: How to split methods ?

Answer (score 0):

You must need to divide your method from one to multiple, call inner methods from your main method. Like, something would be return in your method, like one string then catch that part of the code and create new method and return that string from that new method to main method, Like this way you can split your methods from one to multiple.

In future always remember that, you must not need to create this kind of long methods, its bad coding practise.